# K-means : choose Optimum number of clusters based on graph

Tags: r, k-means

I've come into a situation where I dont understand How to choose the number of clusters. The WithinSS increases suddenly after 6. How/What do I interpret of this graph ?
Background : I've applied PCA on the data set and used 4 PCs. The clustering is done on the PCs. I'm using K-means cluster algorithm in R.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"*The within-cluster sum of squares is a measure of the variability of the observations within each cluster. In general, a cluster that has a small sum of squares is more compact than a cluster that has a large sum of squares. Clusters that have higher values exhibit greater variability of the observations within the cluster.*"

Source [here](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/18/help-and-how-to/modeling-statistics/multivariate/how-to/cluster-k-means/interpret-the-results/all-statistics-and-graphs/)

There are a lots of methods that you can use to identify the right number of clusters, 
 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15376075/cluster-analysis-in-r-determine-the-optimal-number-of-clusters) a great topic.